# Are North American eShop games already ineligible for Club Nintendo coins?

Tags: wii-u, club-nintendo

I just saw [a tweet](https://twitter.com/NintendoAmerica/status/563426860030513154) from Nintendo advertising pre-purchase for Kirby and the Rainbow Curse. I was about to buy it when I remembered that Club Nintendo is shutting down and they're going to stop including Coin vouchers in hard copy game boxes, and presumably at some point stop giving coins for linked eShop purchases too.

Now, there's supposed to be a replacement service. That means if I wait to buy Kirby until after it launches, I'll definitely get points in whatever that program turns out to be. But if I can get Coins today, I'd be happy to redeem them before the current program ends.

Would a pre-purchase today definitely get me Coins? Or am I better off waiting?

Answer (score 2):

Anything released after January 20th 2015 will not be eligible for Club Nintendo coins. Whether or not they will be eligible for whatever Nintendo replaces Club Nintendo with is unknown at this point. Considering that you can redeem your Coins til June, it is unlikely they will announce anything about the replacement in the near future.